# How do you use pandas isin() function when each row is a list?

Tags: python, pandas

For example:

```
import pandas as pd
data = ['A2', 'A5', 'XS', '2X', '8W']
codes = {'codes':[data]}
df = pd.DataFrame(codes)

                  codes
0  [A2, A5, XS, 2X, 8W]
```

Now I want to test to see if certain values are in my list from another list.

```
df['wo'] = df.codes.isin(["8C", "8D", "8E", "8W", "A2"])
```

I keep getting `TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'`
How do I fix this?

Comment: What do you want it to return for you? What is the logic here?

Comment: Eventually either a 1 or 0.

Comment: Note that pandas doesn't have strong support for non-scalar entries.  You're much better off making each element of your list its own row.

Comment: In my codes list there is '8W'; which is also the codes that defines a woman-owned small business from the SBA. So 'wo' should be a 0 or 1.  This is just a sample case for testing.

Comment: So if there is any intersection(common elements) between the two lists, it will be 1 otherwise 0?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## `pandas` and `set`

You can use sets.  When subtracting sets you get set differences.  When comparing sets, you get proper subsets.  When a set differenced with another set is a proper subset of that same set... then there was an intersection.

```
s = df.codes.apply(set)
s - set(["8C", "8D", "8E", "8W", "A2"]) < s

0    True
Name: codes, dtype: bool
```

Comment: This works but it wasn't the solution I was hoping for. I may try converting the list of codes to a string and then us the isin() function.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thanks!